How can I add functionality to a "Select All" Checkbox for a checkbox group on a Screen Flow?

I would like to checkbox group to have all values selected if the Select All checkbox is checked (and vice versa). Is this possible to make?
I have tried making the default value of the checkbox group equal to the Select all checkbox, but that does not work.
